# Correct way in using Laravel 4 User model relations with Sentry 2 package

Tags: php, model, laravel-4, relation, cartalyst-sentry

I'm trying to find out how to return the relations I set up for my User model when using Sentry 2.

Normally, I have a user retrieved like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);

// get some relation
return $user->profile->profile_name;
```

However, now when I have Sentry 2 implemented I can retrieve the logged in user like this:

```
$user = Sentry::getUser();
```

This way I can easily access the `users` table in my DB, but how do I go about fetching the relations and methods I have set up in my `User.php` model?

This seems way to clumpsy, and not Laravel-ish:

```
User::find(Sentry::getUser()->id)->profile->wizard_completed;
```

It seems somewhat... backwards.

Can you guys help me out? =)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Extend Sentry creating your own User model with your relations on it:

```
<?php

use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User as SentryModel;

class User extends SentryModel {

    public function profile()
    {
        return hasOne(...);
    }

}
```

Publish sentry's config:

```
php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentry
```

And tell Sentry to use your model, which now extending Sentry's has all of its functionalities plus yours:

```
'model' => 'User',
```

Then you'll be able to:

```
echo Sentry::getUser()->profile->wizard_completed;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that! But if I tell Sentry to use my model instead, won't some functionality of their model get lost?

Comment: If you are extending (´class User extends SentryModel´) their own model, how could it loose anything? It will have all Sentry's functionality plus yours.

Comment: Than you, It makes perfekt sense that it would extend all its functionality. I just got confused when you said I should change the Sentry config to use my model. But since that model now extends theirs, I get it :) Thank you for your help!